# Multi-Selection horizontal

Tags: css, html, html-select

I'm trying to build a multi-selection like that:

- The height and width of each option is 100.
- The options are listed horizontally.
- **The options have to make a line break if they are out of the browsers width**.

It looks like that at the moment:
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hotLutu/)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
 width:100vw;
}
select {
 padding:0;
 padding-left:1px;
 border:none;
 background-color:#eee;
 width:100vw;
}
option {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:white;
 margin-left:-1px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div id="data">
  <select multiple size="1">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
   <option>11</option>
   <option>12</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>
```

The only thing missing now is the line break.

I hope you can help! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the normal way of inserting line breaks in text. For `<select>` tags, the `white-space` style is changed to `nowrap` by default, so all you need to do is change it back to `normal`:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
 width:100vw;
}
select {
 padding:0;
 padding-left:1px;
 border:none;
 background-color:#eee;
 width:100vw;
 white-space: normal;
 height:200px;
}
option {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:white;
 margin-left:-1px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="data">
 <select multiple size="1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
 </select>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi the following changes should do the trick

Remove `overflow:hidden;` from `#data`

add `overflow:visible;` to `select`

and add `float:left;` to `option`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to select

```
height:200px;
```

And add this to option:

```
float: left;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hotLutu/2/

Comment: Must be your browser, the link in my answer works fine for me