# HTML5 Select Multiple Height To Fit Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

We a trying to get a `select` input element with `multiple` attribute set on, to automatically resize to fit its content.

We have noticed that when setting the `select` element `multiple` to true, we can then change the styling of the child `option` elements.

```
<select multiple>
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
</select>
```

This is great because we can create a more customized user experience...

```
select option{
   display : inline-block;
   padding : 5px;
   border-radius : 3px;
}
```

But the problem is that the size is interpreted by the browser to be "3" and so the height is being set accordingly...

Is there a way to make the select to auto resize to fit the content?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What should your input element look like? Just a single row? Did you try adding the size="1" parameter to the element?

Comment: @obscure yes, its a row. but when too many options are added it causes to exceed the width of the container, they will fall down to the next row...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look here : [Multi-Selection horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571498/multi-selection-horizontal)

Depends on what you want to do !